# JMeter alternative for simple functional testing with CI and AWS ELB HealthCheck

Tags: jmeter, vagrant, automated-tests, amazon-elb

I need to perform simple functional tests (think smoke tests completing in a few seconds per application) on hosted web services to make sure nothing major is broken following an automated deployment.  I don't need robust extraction or assertion logic, and I don't need load testing capability.  JMeter seems like it will do the job but might be overkill.  Are there other open source projects or software products that are better suited?

There are two types of deployments which this test would be used for.  First, in development and the CI pipeline, I'm using Vagrant to test my Chef automation.  After Chef Client runs, I would like to have Vagrant kick off the smoke test.  If the test fails, CI knows to fail the checked in Chef code.  I am currently doing this by having Vagrant run a Powershell provisioner which is a simple script which performs wget's to test calling the web services, just looking to ensure certain fragments of the expected response are present.

The second use case is at AWS where I would like to configure the ELB's HealthCheck to call a web service which would smoke test whatever applications are installed on that server and once successful, return HTTP 200's for all subsequent requests.  The purpose of this would be to ensure that the app has completed the deployment process and has been successfully deployed prior to entering the load balancer.

Bonus Points: Are there any existing services that are able to self discover the websites/services installed on a server and any test scripts that might be present with them, and run them automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [vagrant-serverspec](https://github.com/jvoorhis/vagrant-serverspec) plugin for testing with vagrant
and simple aws elb command to check instance state

```
aws elb describe-instance-health --load-balancer-name my-load-balancer --instances i-7299c809
```

Output:

```
  {
    "InstanceStates": [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-7299c809",
            "ReasonCode": "ELB",
            "State": "OutOfService",
            "Description": "Instance registration is still in progress."
      }
    ]
  }
```

also you may add query for just test state.

```
--query 'InstanceStates[*].State' --output text
```

Valid values: `InService | OutOfService | Unknown`